# submit form in spring MVC by clicking on Link

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there any way to submit the form in spring MVC by clicking on Link or do I need to use the javascript submit method

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't accepted any answer yet on the questions you asked. Please and point and accept appropriate answer on questions asked before. Otherwise people will stop answer you in the future.

Comment: Hi Danny, Thanks for suggestion, yes your answer helped me but for now I am using <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">Submit</a>. I have posted another question regarding this I don't know how I can I proceed with my current question as I can only edit my question.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't accepted any answers on your previous questions.

Comment: Hi Danny, it would be great if you could tell me how I can accept the answer. I am new to this forum. So I don't get any link where I can accept the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery on submit function as the event on url click:

```
$('#formName').submit();
```